How to make animated stack carousel images using flutter
I would like to recreate this animated carousel of card images that has big center image and the next and previous card are both behind with 50% visibility.
What is the best approach to build this using widgets? or any helpful plugin that will help to make this. Below is the example demo.


Either you can use CarouselView or you can use carousel_slider.

Can I stack images using CarouselView? Can you show simple example.

Try this carousel_slider: ^5.0.0 :- https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Tried this package and can do what expected to do but don't know how to stack images like the demo I attached.

play with aspectRatio: 16/9 and viewportFraction: 0.8,

Its now working.

I mean its not working. I can’t stack the items. Maybe can you show how?
